# How can i make my particles act more like a fluid

Tags: javascript, function, class, math, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to create a fluid simulation using sph in javascript i have finally calculated everything so the particles receive a force but the force doesnt seem to work properly and just pushes the particles away from each other randomly because when i add gravity it just goes to to mayhem

My result ideally would be without gravity the particles are evenly distributed without clumps and massive gaps and with gravity it should not explode and flow back and forth

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 20;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 100;
var simMinWidth = 20.0;
var cScale = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / simMinWidth;
var simWidth = canvas.width / cScale;
var simHeight = canvas.height / cScale;
var numParticles = 100;
var radius = 0.2;
var pressuremultiplier = 10
var restdensity = 1

function cX(position) {
  return position.x * cScale;
}

function cY(position) {
  return position.y * cScale;
}

class Particle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.position = new Vector(x, y)
    this.velocity = new Vector(0, 0);
    this.radius = radius;
    this.smoothinglength = 6 * radius
    this.density = 1
    this.pressure = 1
    this.pressureforce = 1
    this.mass = 1
  }
  updateAcceleration() {
    this.calculatedensity(fluidSimulator.particles)
    this.calculatepressure()
    this.calculatepressureforce(fluidSimulator.particles);
    this.acceleration = (this.pressureforce.divScalar(this.density)).add(fluidSimulator.gravity);

  }
  checkboundarys() {
    if (this.position.x - this.radius < 0.0) {
      this.position.x = 0.0 + this.radius;
      this.velocity.x = -fluidSimulator.collisionDamping * this.velocity.x;
    }

    if (this.position.x + this.radius > simWidth) {
      this.position.x = simWidth - this.radius;
      this.velocity.x = -fluidSimulator.collisionDamping * this.velocity.x;
    }

    if (this.position.y - this.radius < 0.0) {
      this.position.y = 0.0 + this.radius;
      this.velocity.y = -fluidSimulator.collisionDamping * this.velocity.y;
    }

    if (this.position.y + this.radius > simHeight) {
      this.position.y = simHeight - this.radius; // Adjusted this line
      this.velocity.y = -fluidSimulator.collisionDamping * this.velocity.y;
    }
  }
  calculatedensity(nearbyparticles) {
    let density = 0;
    for (let cparticle of nearbyparticles) {
      if (cparticle != self) {
        let distance = this.position.distanceFrom(cparticle.position);
        density += cparticle.mass * fluidSimulator.poly6kernel(distance, this.smoothinglength)
      }
    }
    this.density = density;
  }
  calculatepressure() {
    this.pressure = pressuremultiplier * (this.density - restdensity)
  }
  calculatepressureforce(nearbyparticles) {
    let pressureforce = new Vector(0, 0);
    let pressuremagnitude = 0;
    for (let cparticle of nearbyparticles) {
      let distance = this.position.distanceFrom(cparticle.position);
      if (distance !== 0) {
        let directionvector = new Vector((this.position.x - cparticle.position.x) / distance, (this.position.y - cparticle.position.y) / distance);

        // Check if the denominator (cparticle.density) is not zero
        if (cparticle.density !== 0) {
          pressuremagnitude = cparticle.pressure * cparticle.mass * fluidSimulator.spikykernelderrivative(distance, this.smoothinglength) / cparticle.density;
          pressureforce.x += directionvector.x * (pressuremagnitude);
          pressureforce.y += directionvector.y * (pressuremagnitude)
          if (distance < this.smoothinglength) {
            //console.log(pressureforce)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    this.pressureforce = pressureforce.mulScalar(-1);
  }

  simulateParticle() {
    this.updateAcceleration();
    this.velocity = this.velocity.add(this.acceleration.mulScalar(fluidSimulator.timestep));
    this.position = this.position.add(this.velocity.mulScalar(fluidSimulator.timestep));
    this.checkboundarys()

  }

}

class SPHFluidSimulator {
  constructor() {
    //simulation constants
    this.timestep = 1 / 30;
    this.gravity = new Vector(0, 0);
    this.collisionDamping = 1;
    this.particleSpacing = 0.1;
    this.particles = [];



  }
  poly6kernel(r, h) {
    let influence = 0
    if (r >= 0 & r <= h) {
      influence = (h ** 2 - r ** 2) ** 3

    }
    return (315 / (64 * Math.PI * h ** 9)) * influence

  }
  spikykernelderrivative(r, h) {
    let influence = 0
    if (r >= 0 & r <= h) {
      influence = -3 * (h - r) ** 2
    }
    return (15 / (Math.PI * h ** 6)) * influence


  }
  initialiseParticle(particle) {
    // Add a particle to the simulation and update the grid
    this.particles.push(particle);
  }


}

function generateParticlesRandom() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {
    let particleX = Math.random() * simWidth;
    let particleY = Math.random() * simHeight;
    let particle = new Particle(particleX, particleY);
    fluidSimulator.initialiseParticle(particle);
  }
}

function physics() {
  for (const particle of fluidSimulator.particles) {
    particle.simulateParticle();
  }
  //console.log(fluidSimulator.particles[0])

}

function draw() {

  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.fillStyle = "#005EB8";
  for (let i = 0; i < numParticles; i++) {
    let particle = fluidSimulator.particles[i];
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(cX(particle.position), cY(particle.position), cScale * radius, 0.0, 2.0 * Math.PI);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();
  };
}

function simulate() {
  physics();
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(simulate);
}

var fluidSimulator = new SPHFluidSimulator();
generateParticlesRandom();
simulate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ronenness.github.io/Vector2js/vector2js.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations)?

Comment: Navier-Stokes == Newton's equation of motion for fluids in an Eulerian reference frame.  Not easy to solve.  You might want to do some research to find Javascript physics libraries that include fluid effects, unless your goal is to write your own from scratch.  Is your Canvas a 2D or 3D view of the flow field?  The latter is much more difficult.  If you are willing to exclude certain physics you can simplify things (e.g. irrotational flow, etc)

Comment: yeah i  learnt the momentum equation which is what i am using to set the acceleration i am using a 2d view of my fluid and i want to simulate fluid flow with particles without viscoscity